# Wortherkunft bei der Redewendung "in der Blase sein"?

Tags: meaning, idiom

Die Bedeutung ist mit ungefähr klar, sprich man ist abgeschottet (?)

Aber was ist die ursprüngliche Bedeutung, um welche Blase genau handelt es sich?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine direkte Übertragung der [Filter bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble) zur hiesigen: [Filterblase:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filterblase)

> Die Filterblase (englisch filter bubble) oder Informationsblase ist ein Begriff der Medienwissenschaft, der vom Internetaktivisten Eli Pariser in seinem gleichnamigen Buch von 2011 verwendet wird. Laut Pariser entstehe die Filterblase, weil Webseiten versuchen, algorithmisch vorauszusagen, welche Informationen der Benutzer auffinden möchte – dies basierend auf den verfügbaren Informationen über den Benutzer (beispielsweise Standort des Benutzers, Suchhistorie und Klickverhalten). Daraus resultiere eine Isolation gegenüber Informationen, die nicht dem Standpunkt des Benutzers entsprechen.

Ergänzend sei hinzugefügt, dass nicht nur die bösen Maschinen und Konzerne solche Blasen erzeugen, der Begriff also mittlerweile in erweiterter Bedeutung benutzt wird:

> [Das führt zu einer selbstgebastelten Filterblase](https://steadynews.de/marketing/was-ist-eigentlich-eine-filterblase-sachen-die-man-wissen-sollte), die zu der Algorithmen-Blase hinzukommt. Wir wählen in wenigen Augenblicken aus, ob uns ein Text, ein Video, ein Musikstück oder ein Diskussionsstrang interessiert. Wir rasen durch das Web mit einem ständigen „Ja/Nein-Button“, klicken uns durch anfängliche Anfänge, ohne das Ganze zu prüfen. So basteln wir uns unsere personifizierten Informationen und Meinungen zusammen und geben konträren Inhalten und Meinungen immer seltener eine Chance.

Zwar sind "[Blasen blöd](https://www.zeit.de/2017/34/algorithmen-filterblase-meinungen-selbstbetrug/komplettansicht)", aber deren schiere Existenz wird mittlerweile als [übertriebene Metapher kritisiert](https://motherboard.vice.com/de/article/pam5nz/deshalb-ist-filterblase-die-blodeste-metapher-des-internets). Denn diesem [populären Theorem fehlt die empirische Fundierung](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-658-17501-6_17).

Comment: *Anzweifelndes Kritisieren* kenne ich nicht, in wiefern geht das über *Kritisieren* hinaus? Sollte der letzte Satz mit *Denn* anfangen?

Comment: @Guidot: Reinkultürliches Kritisieren anerkennt die Existenz von x, bewertet sie aber negativ. Anzweifelndes Kritisieren stellt (üblicherweise wohl: ergänzend) die Existenz von x in Frage. Insofern sind das zwei sehr unterschiedliche Dinge. Oder willst du diesen Unterschied etwa anzweifelnd kritisieren?